# Issue Rotating Canvas Shape WIth Arrow Keys

Tags: javascript, rotation, html5-canvas

I would like the left and right arrow keys to rotate my canvas shape clockwise and anticlockwise, respectively. Currently the shape moves only linearly.

In the long run, I am trying to replicate the movement of my ROS (Robot Operating System) TurtleSim using this javascript code, and the left & right keys rotate the turtlesim in this way. (I am fairly new to javascript.)

```
<script>
function Parent(){
    //diffColor = false;
    mainCanvas.load();
    tracker = new track(30, 50, "white", 30, 120); //create object that will move with keys;

    click();
    //touch();
    //animate();
    //mapCanvas.load();
}

function click(){
        window.addEventListener("click", getClickPosition, false);

    function getClickPosition(e){
        tracker.distanceX = e.clientX - (tracker.width / 2); //move tracker to near center of tracker; clientX gets horizontal coordinate of cursor
        tracker.distanceY = e.clientY - (tracker.height / 2);

        }
}


var mainCanvas = {
    canvas : document.createElement("canvas"),
    load: function(){

        this.canvas.width = (window.innerWidth)/2;
        this.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
        this.ctx1 = this.canvas.getContext("2d");

        document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
        this.interval = setInterval(moveTracker, 20);

        window.addEventListener ("keydown", function(e){
            console.log(e.keyCode);
            mainCanvas.key = e.keyCode; //execute movement when key pressed
        });
        window.addEventListener ("keyup", function(e){
                mainCanvas.key = false; //stop movement once key is released
                });

    },

    clear: function(){
        this.ctx1.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
    }
}

    function track(width, height, color, distanceX, distanceY, theSquare){ 
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.speedX = 0;
    this.speedY = 0;
    this.distanceX = distanceX;
    this.distanceY = distanceY;
    this.rotationSpeedRight = 0;
    this.rotationSpeedLeft= 0;
    this.rotationLeft = rotationLeft;
    this.rotationRight = rotationRight;
    console.log("inside track()");

    this.update = function(theSquare){
        ctx = mainCanvas.ctx1;
        ctx.fillStyle = color;
        ctx.fillRect(this.distanceX, this.distanceY, this.width, this.height, this.rotationLeft, this.rotationRight);
        ctx.rotate(45*Math.PI/180);
        ctx.save();
        ctx.restore();
    }
    this.newPosition = function(){
    this.rotation += this.rotationSpeed;
    this.distanceX += this.speed * Math.cos(this.rotation);
    this.distanceY += this.speed * Math.sin(this.rotation);
    }
}

function moveTracker(){ //recognize keys from keyboard
    mainCanvas.clear();
    tracker.speedX = 0;
    tracker.speedY = 0;
    tracker.rotationSpeedRight = 0;
    tracker.rotationSpeedLeft = 0;
    if (mainCanvas.key && mainCanvas.key == 37) //left key; should move anticlockwise
        tracker.rotationSpeedLeft = -1;
    if (mainCanvas.key && mainCanvas.key == 38) //down key
        tracker.speedY = -1;
    if (mainCanvas.key && mainCanvas.key == 39) //right key; should move clockwise;
        tracker.rotationSpeedRight = 1;
    if (mainCanvas.key && mainCanvas.key == 40) //up key
        tracker.speedY=1;

    tracker.newPosition();
    tracker.update();
}
```

Comment: Store a rotation and rotation speed the same way you store the position ("distance") and speed. Change it in your moveTracker function (based on the key presses) and use it with [save](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/save), [rotate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/save) and [restore](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/restore) around the fillRect in your update function.

Comment: @BaliBalo : Thank you for your reply! I've tried to implement your suggestion, but now I'm getting an error in my browser. I believe it's because I haven't used the rotate() and save() correctly; could you take a look at my editted code and show me where I'm going wrong?

Comment: You don't need two rotations, the rotation is just one value. The order of operation should also be this in your case `save -> rotate -> draw -> restore`. I'll write an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as a "left rotation" and a "right rotation", they both refer to the same thing. You only need one rotation value, it is the current angle of your drawing.

I also assume you want your up key to go in whichever direction you are facing rather than always up, so you can switch the speed values to only one value as well, the speed in the current direction. This basically changes your coordinate system from [cartesian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system) (x, y) to [polar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system) (angle and distance).
To know the final change on the X-Y plane of a move based on rotation and speed, you have to use `speed * cos(angle)` for X and `speed * sin(angle)` for Y (based on trigonometry).

`rotate` needs to be called before you draw your rectangle (it's basically saying "everything that I will do next will need to be rotated by that amount") and `save` and `restore` need to be called around all that, to cancel the rotation once you are done drawing your rotated shape.

Another note: `rotate` rotates the canvas around the origin (0, 0). To rotate around the center of your element, which is probably what you want to do, you will need to first `translate` to the position, then not forget to offset the position at which you draw the rectangle to take into account that initial translation.

A potential update of the bottom part of your code would be:

```
function track(width, height, color, distanceX, distanceY, rotation){
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.distanceX = distanceX || 0;
    this.distanceY = distanceY || 0;
    this.speed = 0;
    this.rotation = rotation || 0;
    this.rotationSpeed = 0;

    this.update = function(){
        ctx = mainCanvas.ctx1;
        ctx.fillStyle = color;
        ctx.save();
        ctx.translate(this.distanceX, this.distanceY);
        ctx.rotate(this.rotation);
        ctx.fillRect(-this.width / 2, -this.height / 2, this.width, this.height);
        ctx.restore();
    }
    this.newPosition = function(){
        this.rotation += this.rotationSpeed;
        this.distanceX += this.speed * Math.cos(this.rotation);
        this.distanceY += this.speed * Math.sin(this.rotation);
    }
}

function moveTracker(){ //recognize keys from keyboard
    mainCanvas.clear();
    tracker.speed = 0;
    tracker.rotationSpeed = 0;
    // Adjust the values as you need here
    if (mainCanvas.key == 37) //left key
        tracker.rotationSpeed = -0.5 / Math.PI;
    if (mainCanvas.key == 38) //up key
        tracker.speed = 3;
    if (mainCanvas.key == 39) //right key
        tracker.rotationSpeed = 0.5 / Math.PI;
    if (mainCanvas.key == 40) //down key
        tracker.speed = -3;

    tracker.newPosition();
    tracker.update();
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e08vbdpy/) (rough version)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I will implement this into my code!

Comment: May I also ask though: how does the distance equation relates to the Pythagorean theorem? (Sorry for this delayed enquiry; I am no longer the under pressure I was before to complete this project, so I am now trying to understand and expand on this for future use on my robot. )

Comment: @SK that's how converting polar coordinates (angle and distance) to Cartesian (x and y). Can't have a lengthy explanation in comments but basically that makes a right angled triangle with two of the sides along the x and y axes - here are a couple of sources: [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system#Converting_between_polar_and_Cartesian_coordinates), [mathsisfun](https://www.mathsisfun.com/polar-cartesian-coordinates.html) (more detailed)

Comment: I just realized why you may be confused. That is not actually the Pythagorean theorem this way around, just trigonometry relationships - sorry